# How I can access to one Struct property that implements two protocols?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Im just learning Swift 4 and I have some troubles trying to access a property of an struct that have to implement 2 protocols

here is my struct

```
struct FigureA {
    static func load() -> Model {
        return Model.make(
            name: "FigureName", 
            status: "Painted", 
            image: UIImage(named: "FigureA"), 
            description: "Good figure")
    }
}
```

here the protocol 1

```
protocol ListModel: class {
    var name: String { get }
    var status: String { get }
    var image: UIImage? { get }
}
```

here the protocol 2

```
protocol DetailModel: ListModel {
    var categoryName: String { get }
    var modelDescription: String? { get }
}
```

And I want to get the access to the description of the Struct but I don't know how at all.

Can someone give me a bit of light.

Comment: @Uwe Keim please don't add unnecessary tags to question. The Swift4 tag shouldn't be used unless the question is about a specific change related to the specific Swift version, which is clearly not the case here.

Comment: The `DetailModel` protocol isn't used anywhere in your code, so you should update your question to include a [mcve]. The declaration for `Model` is missing too.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is good start for you:**

```
protocol BaseProtocol {
    var id: Int { get set }
}

protocol PersonProtocol: BaseProtocol {
    var firstName: String { get set }
    var lastName: String { get set }
    var name: String { get }
}

struct Person: PersonProtocol {
    var id: Int
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var name: String { return firstName + " " + lastName }
}

//≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Create Struct Instance & Print properties.
        let person = Person(id: 1001, firstName: "Manish", lastName: "Rathi")
        print(person.id)
        print(person.firstName)
        print(person.lastName)
        print(person.name)
    }
}
```

**#HappyCoding**